# Group policy and OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

Is there any sort of group policy mechanic for OpenLDAP? And just like the GUI tool OpenLDAP is there a version of the GPMC for OpenLDAP's group policy?

Answer (score 1):

OpenLDAP is just an LDAP server. Of course, you could use it to store something like group policies (in fact, the GP equivalent on MacOS is stored inside the OpenLDAP directory part of OpenDirectory), but there is no general mechanism for group policies on Linux or any other unixoid OS.